# Friend put hand on mother's head and swore a lie, is the mother going to get death or misfortune

Tags: halal-haram, punishment

Asak brothers and sisters, recently one of my friends told me that his mother made him put his hand on her head and he swore a false wallahi for something that happened in the past, his mother said that if he is lying she would be also suffering punishment, is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Allah says in the holy Quran: (Al-An'am (The Cattle) - 6:164)

> وَلاَ تَزِرُ وَازِرَةٌ وِزْرَ أُخْرَى

Translation:

> And whatever [wrong] any human being commits rests upon himself alone; and no bearer of burdens shall be made to bear another's burden.

Which means that only the person who committed the sin (in this case, swearing a false promise: lie) is the one who will undertake the burden alone.

Allah is just and will never make someone pay for the mistake of another person.

My guess is that the mother wanted the son to tell the truth and she pressured him into thinking that she is will be in danger if he does not tell the truth.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that only applies in the HereAfter. In this world, a person's sins can and do affect others.

Comment: @Shadi Yes: sins affect others. Punishment for these sins are inflicted upon the committer  of such sin, not anyone else. How is it your fault if I committed a murder?

Comment: @Ahmed Yeah, the questioner asked if such a sin could affect someone else, and you responded that only each one takes on his burden. The questioner is obviously talking about this life. Allah knows best

Comment: @Shadi the questioner asked if the sin of swearing a false promise will cause danger to his mother’s life. The only way that can happen is if Allah intervened in this life and shortened the life of the mother as a way to punish the sinner. And that is just unfair, whether it is in this life or the other. Allah is fair and shall not have the mother pay for the sin of her son.

Comment: No brother, you can't say what Allah will or won't do. Swearing by Allah is not a whatever/okay thing to do. And again, "fairnes" "justice" is in the next life, not in this life, obviously. Allah knows best.

Comment: @Shadi I am not saying that swearing a false promise has no effect.. I am saying that it is wrong and deserves punishment. But the punishment shall not be inflicted on innocent bystanders. The punishment will be inflicted on the sinners. I know it is hard for you to understand, but let's take a simple example. If you point a gun at a kid and shoot, the kid will die and you have committed a murder. You will deserve punishment for this sin. The kid is affected, having his life taken away, not by punishment, but by the effect of your sin. I hope I made it clear.